# CSS drop up menu not displayed correctly

Tags: css, menu

I'm having some trouble with changing a CSS drop down menu to a drop up menu. I think I'm almost there, but for some reason some of the buttons are not displayed correctly (the text is moving downwards, but the menu is moving upwards). See crisislab.nl for the code in action.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#navigation {
    width: 980px;
    height: 38px;
}

#navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 220px;
}

#navigation li:hover {
    background: transparent  url(gfx/navigation_hover.png) repeat;
}

#navigation li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 33px;
    line-height: 38px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation li ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent  url(gfx/navigation_hover.png) left top repeat;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-width: 100%;
    display:none; 
    left:-1px;
}

#navigation li:hover ul {
    bottom: 38px;
    display:block;   
}

#navigation li ul li {
    background: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#navigation li ul li:hover {
    background: none;
    background-color: #2a51b5;
}

#navigation li ul li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 8px 10px;
    line-height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code (+ relevant HTML) on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'll try. Never did that before.

Comment: Since nothing happens I probably did something wrong, but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/TMx6y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having a hard time finding bugs, always replicate and break the code into smallest simplest chunks.

Hope this would help: http://jsfiddle.net/ccS7q/

But you wouldn't be able to achieve drop up menu with the sublists listing upwards unless you use jquery or javascript with it. The fiddle above can't do listing upwards, you could though adjust manually the `ul li.menu-item ul` `top` value as the listing lengthens. Though its a lot of work. I would advise you to use jquery instead.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Unfortunately I'm unable write anything in jquery, so a lot of work it is..

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `bottom: 38px;` from below code:

```
#navigation li:hover ul {
    bottom: 38px;/*Just Remove This*/
    display: block;
}
```

Add top:0 to #navigation ul li ul li

```
#navigation li ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    top: 0;/*Add This*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: This results in the menu not being displayed at all (see crisislab.nl)

Comment: Hey! have u removed complete css block? I just asked to remove bottom:38px  from css.

Comment: Thanks, but that's strange. I'm using Firefox as well. (On IE it isnt working for me either)

Comment: Let me check. Thought i just deleted the one part

Comment: You're right. I put it back (but it still doesn't function properly).

Comment: There are lots of changes to be done in your website css & html. And i am close to make it work. I'll be good if u send me the html & css of this website my email: svsbe85@yahoo.com